# difference (if any) between a variable & an identifier

Tags: javascript, variables

**Javascript**

```
let num = 10;
```

in this case, is `num` a variable or an identifier?!
can someone explain with an example the **difference (if any) between a variable & an identifier**?

Comment: An *identifier* is some string of characters that can be used as a variable name. A *variable* is a symbol declared in some context, and its name must be a valid identifier.

Comment: The concept *identifier* appears in the language syntax in more situations than variables. For example, a function name must be an identifier, as must be function parameter names.

Comment: Think of an Identifer as a "label" for something like a bucket, which holds a value. Or more importantly a reference to a value in Javascript. let bucketOfDirt = "sand";
The identifier for my variable is `bucketOfDirt`, in other words its a name given to a `variable, function, property`.

There are some rules for naming e.g. you cannot use keywords in JavaScript as variable names